# The djConfig attribute in Script tag

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

All, Forgive me I just began to learn the `Dojo`, I noticed one of the way to reference Dojo framework to page looks like below :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Dojo djConfig Tutorial&lt;/title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.4.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
            djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But I didn't understand the attribute `djConfig` in the `Script` tag, I also read through the reference of [document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) about `Script` tag. but didn't found any part of doc tell about this attributes. So Where does `djConfig` attribute come from? Does it means I can define any attributes in the `Script` tag?

Let say:

```
<script src="test.js" myTag ="Test"></script>
```

Thanks.

**Added**

I did some test with Jquery. Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"  type="text/javascript" myTag="test"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        $(function(){
            alert($("p").html());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The page just works fine(showed the content of p) without any error. but the attribute "myTag" in the script tag just is ignored by the page.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `djConfig` or `data-dojo-config` attribute (or `dojoConfig` variable) all do the same thing, they allow you to configure certain aspects of Dojo. There is an article about it called: [Configuring Dojo with dojoConfig](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/).

All modules can make use of that configuration object by using the `dojo/_base/config` module.

There are a few well known configuration properties that are commonly used, for example:

- `async` is used by the Dojo module loader to load modules in an asynchronous way
- `parseOnLoad` is used by the **dojo/parser** module to parse all widgets on the page (in markup) when the page is ready
- `packages` is used by the Dojo AMD loader to define the package that it can use to load modules
- `baseUrl` is used by the Dojo AMD loader to define the base URL where the packages can be found (unless different in `packages`)

---

To your question if you can define any attribute in the script tag.. you can do it, but nothing will happen with it probably (unless you do something with it by yourself). In fact, in HTML5 you can add any attributes you like by using the `data-` prefix. For example, the following is valid in HTML5:

```
<a href="#" data-myTag="Test"></a>
```

Nothing will happen with it, but it's valid.

You can also add any property you like to `djConfig` as well, which you can then read by using the [`dojo/_base/config`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/config.html) module.

Comment: +1Thanks your reply, I did some test for it . Please review my updated post. Could please tell me more about it ? How can I defined the attribute like `djConfig` for script tag ? thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, what do you expect that `myTag="test"` does? Like I said in my answer, it's valid HTML but nothing will happen with it... it's just an attribute.

Comment: I just expected the `myTag="test"` can be defined a global variable (like var myTag="test" ;) when the script file the `src` pointed to is loaded. Is it possible ? Thanks .

Comment: It's not possible out of the box, so you will have to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, Any `How-To` document to read? Could you please give some to read.